# Почему возвращается Can't call method "value" on an undefined value?

Tags: perl

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $outfile = "out.htm";
my $url = "https://id.rambler.ru/login-20/login/";
my $username = "test";
my $password = "pass";
my $cookiefile = 'cookies.txt';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_name('login_form');
$mech->field(login => $username);
$mech->field(password => $password);
$mech->click();
$mech->follow_link(text => "Войти", n => 1);
my $output_page = $mech->content();
open(OUTFILE, ">$outfile");
print OUTFILE "$output_page";
close(OUTFILE);
```

Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 769.

Comment: что-то я в документации вижу совсем другие примеры, да и в https://metacpan.org/source/PETDANCE/WWW-Mechanize-0.48/lib%2FWWW%2FMechanize.pm исходниках ничего близкого к вызову `->value` в 7** строке не вижу. рассказывай подробности. рассказывай какая версия у модуля. покажи что в 76* строках в твоём /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/WWW/Mechanize.pm

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь передать поле в несуществующую форму или в несуществующее поле, соответственно у вас ошибка.

1. для начала выведите куда-то `print $mech->content;` и найдите глазами форму, которую вы заполняете.
2. проверьте, что вы действительно получили форму (что получили от метода формы)